# How to create terms and condition page in tab bar application

Tags: iphone, ios

I have a tab bar based application and I wish to create a terms and conditions page, shown only when the application is launched for the first time.

How do I do this?

Answer (score 6):

You can show terms and conditions in UIAlertView as text or present a view controller modally. Have a Bool which would be set to YES if user selects Accept for terms and conditions and save this using NSUserDefaults. Everytime app is launched check the BOOL.

I have created a sample project using XCode default template `tabbed application`. And here is code snippet that shows Alert View with terms and conditions until user accepts it.

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
    self.window = [[[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]] autorelease];
    if(![[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] valueForKey:@"acceptTermsAndConditionsBool"])
    {
        UIAlertView* tempAlert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Terms And Conditions" message:@"Please read the terms and conditions below for using the app. We may need the app to send us app usage.. blah blah blah" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"Deny" otherButtonTitles:@"Accept", nil];
        [tempAlert show];
        [tempAlert release];
    }

    // Override point for customization after application launch.
    UIViewController *viewController1 = [[[FirstViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"FirstViewController" bundle:nil] autorelease];
    UIViewController *viewController2 = [[[SecondViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"SecondViewController" bundle:nil] autorelease];
    self.tabBarController = [[[UITabBarController alloc] init] autorelease];
    self.tabBarController.viewControllers = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:viewController1, viewController2, nil];
    self.window.rootViewController = self.tabBarController;
    [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
    return YES;
}

- (void)alertView:(UIAlertView *)alertView clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex
{
    switch (buttonIndex) 
    {
        case 0:
        {
            exit(0);
            break;
        }
        case 1:
        {
            [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:@"YES" forKey:@"acceptTermsAndConditionsBool"];
            break;
        }

        default:
            break;
    }
}
```